# Send multi message using jquery plugin in multi-row data?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i use jquery.form to send a form, but in may case below how use this jquery plugin

```
$('#htmlForm').ajaxForm({ 
    target: '#htmlExampleTarget', 
    success: function() { 
        $('#htmlExampleTarget').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#htmlForm').hide();
    } 
});
```

for($i=1;$i<= 10;$i++){

//form $1

form name="form$i" action="blabla.php"

input type="text" name="name$i" />

input type="text" name="name$i" />

input type="submit" name="submit" /

}

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of id and loop through the forms. For the target take an id like #htmlExampleTarget1.

```
var i = 1;
$('.htmlForm').each(function () {
   var object = $(this);
   object.ajaxForm({
      target: '#htmlExampleTarget' + i, 
      success: function() { 
         $('#htmlExampleTarget' + i).fadeIn('slow');
         object.hide();
       }
   });
   i++;
});
```

Comment: how did you integrated, did you changed your php code respectively and what exactly didn#t work (i.e. js error output)?

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var i = 1;
 $('#htmlForm').each(function () {
  var object = $(this);
  object.ajaxForm({
   target: '#htmlExampleTarget' + i, 
   success: function() { 
    $('#htmlExampleTarget' + i).fadeIn('slow');
    object.hide();
     }
  });
    i++;
 });
});
</script>
<?php
$i=1;
foreach ($data as $item) {
 
 <div id="htmlExampleTarget<?php echo $i;?>"></div>
 <form id="htmlForm" method="post" action="sendmail.php">
  //form here
 </form>

}
?>

or you can view the demo at easyhired.com

Comment: Yes, because you are using an id not a class, as I showed in my example! Change `<form id="htmlForm" ...>` to `<form class="htmlForm">` and your script from `$('#htmlForm').each ...` to `$('.htmlForm').each ...` and try again.